# Collect lines of a buffer

Tags: elisp

There's process output that needs to be parsed per line, into structs.

```
sug skProc  strutils.capitalize proc (string): string{.noSideEffect.}
sug skProc  strutils.quoteIfContainsWhite   proc (string): string
sug skProc  system.gorge    proc (string, string): string
sug skProc  system.of   proc (T, S): bool{.noSideEffect.}
sug skProc  system.definedInScope   proc (expr): bool{.noSideEffect.}
sug skIterator  system.items    iterator (cstring): char{.inline.}
sug skProc  system.ord  proc (T): int{.noSideEffect.}
```

This data is inside a buffer. So how do I read each line and pass it
to a function which returns a parsed representation and collect all
lines in the end?

EDIT: The code for parsing the lines (not debugged):

```
(defstruct nimrod-sug type namespace name signature)

(defun nimrod-parse-suggestion-line (line)
  (let ((split (split-string line "[\t\n]")))
    (make-nimrod-sug
     :type (nth 1 split)
     :namespace (first (split-string (nth 2 split) "\\."))
     :name (second (split-string (nth 2 split) "\\."))
     :signature (nth 3 split))
```

Comment: What should the output structs look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some minor changes to the parser:

```
(defun nimrod-parse-suggestion-line (line)
  (destructuring-bind (_ type fn &rest sig) (split-string line "[[:space:]]+" t)
    (make-nimrod-sug :type      type 
                     :namespace (first  (split-string fn "\\."))
                     :name      (second (split-string fn "\\."))
                     :signature (apply 'concat sig))))
```

Assuming the name of the buffer is `*output*`, you can parse it like so:

```
(with-current-buffer "*output*" 
  (mapcar 'nimrod-parse-suggestion-line
          (split-string (buffer-string) "[\r\n]" t)))

; => ([cl-struct-nimrod-sug "skProc" "strutils" "capitalize" "proc(string):string{.noSideEffect.}"] ...)
```

If you're currently visiting the output buffer, you won't need the `with-current-buffer` wrapper.